# Override api.onchange method

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-11

I'm trying to override the _onchange_product_id_check_availability method from the sale.order.line class in order to change the availavility calculus.

But odoo is ignoring the overriden method and still uses the original implementation, my implementation is called only if I rename the method.

this is the original method:

```
@api.onchange('product_uom_qty', 'product_uom', 'route_id')
    def _onchange_product_id_check_availability(self):
        if not self.product_id or not self.product_uom_qty or not self.product_uom:
            self.product_packaging = False
            return {}
        if self.product_id.type == 'product':
            precision = self.env['decimal.precision'].precision_get('Product Unit of Measure')
            product = self.product_id.with_context(warehouse=self.order_id.warehouse_id.id)
            product_qty = self.product_uom._compute_quantity(self.product_uom_qty, self.product_id.uom_id)
            if float_compare(product.virtual_available, product_qty, precision_digits=precision) == -1:
                is_available = self._check_routing()
                if not is_available:
                    message =  _('You plan to sell %s %s but you only have %s %s available in %s warehouse.') % \
                            (self.product_uom_qty, self.product_uom.name, product.virtual_available, product.uom_id.name, self.order_id.warehouse_id.name)
                    # We check if some products are available in other warehouses.
                    if float_compare(product.virtual_available, self.product_id.virtual_available, precision_digits=precision) == -1:
                        message += _('\nThere are %s %s available accross all warehouses.') % \
                                (self.product_id.virtual_available, product.uom_id.name)

                    warning_mess = {
                        'title': _('Not enough inventory!'),
                        'message' : message
                    }
                    return {'warning': warning_mess}
        return {}
```

and this is what I'm trying to implement:

```
class SaleOrderLine(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'sale.order.line'


    @api.onchange('product_uom_qty', 'product_uom', 'route_id')
    def _onchange_product_id_check_availability(self):
        if not self.product_id or not self.product_uom_qty or not self.product_uom:
            self.product_packaging = False
            return {}
        if self.product_id.type == 'product':
            precision = self.env['decimal.precision'].precision_get('Product Unit of Measure')
            product = self.product_id.with_context(warehouse=self.order_id.warehouse_id.id)
            product_qty = self._calculate_availabilty()
            if float_compare(product.virtual_available, product_qty, precision_digits=precision) == -1:
                is_available = self._check_routing()
                if not is_available:
                    message =  _('You plan to sell %s %s but you only have %s %s available in %s warehouse.') % \
                            (product_qty, self.product_uom.name, product.virtual_available, product.uom_id.name, self.order_id.warehouse_id.name)
                    # We check if some products are available in other warehouses.
                    if float_compare(product.virtual_available, self.product_id.virtual_available, precision_digits=precision) == -1:
                        message += _('\nThere are %s %s available accross all warehouses.') % \
                                (self.product_id.virtual_available, product.uom_id.name)

                    warning_mess = {
                        'title': _('Not enough inventory!'),
                        'message' : message
                    }
                    return {'warning': warning_mess}
        return {}


    def _calculate_availabilty(self):
        pdb.set_trace()
        if self.product_uom.name == "Piece(s)":
            return self.product_uom_qty
        if self.product_uom.name == "Kilogram":
            if(self.product_id.theoric_weight == 0 or self.product_uom_qty==0):
                return self.product_uom_qty
            return self.product_uom_qty/self.product_id.theoric_weight
        pass
```

Comment: Have you added to your `__manifest__.py` the module `sale_stock` to the `depends` array and restarted the Odoo service and updated your module after that?

Comment: @forvas omg thanks! this worked ! :) thank you very much!! . I had sale and stock as dependencies but didn't thought I had to add this one too.

Comment: then I post it as an answer a bit more explained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `_onchange_product_id_check_availability` is defined in `sale_stock` module.

If you want to replace its behaviour don't forget to add the `sale_stock` module in the `depends` array of your `__manifest__.py`. Otherwise your method won't be called and the source code will be executed as always.

```
'depends': [
    'sale_stock',
    ...
],
```